# How to implement application prevalence using dartvm?

Tags: dart, prevayler

What options exist to implement application prevalence (think Prevayler) using dartvm on the server ?
I am looking for a pure Dart solution (no inter-process sockets with Java/Prevayler)

Any existing code or project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any object-persistance databases for Dart yet. If you are just looking for a way to serialization object that you could write to disk, there is a [serialization library](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/serialization), and another [serializers library](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/serializers).

You might also want to try the [MongoDB driver for Dart](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mongo_dart) and the [objectory library](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/objectory) for "object document mapping".

Comment: I was hoping for a pure in-memory solution with disk snapshots of full state, the way Prevayler works or some SmallTalk like image file thingy or a java2dart conversion of Prevayler. Still early days...